# Recursive Type or Dependency Context too Complex

Tags: c++, templates

Sorry if this has come up before, I have spent a while looking through for a similar question but I can't see any questions where this

I was writing some code that recursively computes a matrix determinant using the Laplace expansion - this requires working out minor matrices which I have implemented as a class holding a reference to the actual matrix and providing similar functions (such as size and operator()) which return the correct values for the minor matrix. The minor matrix class needs to be able to accept either the base matrix class or another minor matrix class and so needs to be templated, the same for the determinant function.

However, my code (compiled on VS2017) produces the error 'C1202: Recursive type or function dependency context too complex'. Following is a minimal example the reproduces the error:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
    typedef T type;

    A(T value) : value(value) {}
    type get_value() const { return value; }
private:
    T value;
};

template <typename T>
class B
{
public:
    typedef typename T::type type;

    B(const T& t) : t(t) {}
    type get_value() const { return t.get_value() - 1; }
private:
    const T& t;
};

template <typename T>
typename T::type foo(const T& t)
{
    if (t.get_value() == 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return t.get_value() + foo(B<T>(t));
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << foo(A<int>(5));
    std::cin.ignore();
}
```

(I think this should print 15 if it compiled).

Any input would be appreciated.

Edit: This is the non-minimal code (as requested) - dependent on the boost::ublas library

```
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
#include <iostream> 

template <typename Matrix>
class matrix_minor
{
public:
    typedef boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double>::const_reference const_reference;
    typedef boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double>::size_type size_type;

    matrix_minor(const Matrix& A, unsigned int i, unsigned int j) :
        A(A), i(i), j(j) {}

    size_type size1() const { return A.size1() - 1; }

    size_type size2() const { return A.size2() - 1; }
    const_reference operator () (size_type i_, size_type j_) const
    {
        return A(
                (i_ >= i ? i_ + 1 : i_),
                (j_ >= j ? j_ + 1 : j_)
                );
    }

private:
    const Matrix& A;
    unsigned int i, j;
};

template <typename Matrix>
double det(const Matrix& A)
{
    if (A.size1() != A.size2())
        throw "Matrix must be square";

    unsigned int n = A.size1(); //Size of the matrix

    //Early returns for special cases 
    if (n == 1)
        return A(0, 0);
    else if (n == 2)
        return A(0, 0) * A(1, 1) - A(1, 0) * A(0, 1);

    unsigned int i = 0; //Row over which to compute the determinant
    double d = 0; //Value of the determinant
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
        d += (j % 2 == 0 ? 1 : -1) * A(i, j) * det(matrix_minor<Matrix>(A, i, j));
    }
    return d;
}

int main()
{
    boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double> m(3, 3, 1);
    m(0, 0) = 2; 
    m(1, 1) = 3;
    //m = ( (2,1,1), (1,1,1), (1,1,1) )
    std::cout << det(m); //Should print 2
}
```

Comment: Can you post the matrix code that has the recursive template installation? I'm not sure that your example maps back onto that use case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've found, you can't recursively construct a template type with runtime values, as the template instantiation has to stop somehow.

A different idea would be to modify `matrix_minor` to not template nest, at the expense of a more difficult implementation.

```
template <typename Matrix>
class matrix_minor
{
public:
    typedef boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double>::const_reference const_reference;
    typedef boost::numeric::ublas::matrix<double>::size_type size_type;

    matrix_minor(const Matrix& A, unsigned int i, unsigned int j) :
        A(A), is({i}), js({j}) {}

    matrix_minor(const matrix_minor<Matrix>& inner, unsigned int i, unsigned int j) :
        A(inner.A), is(inner.is), js(inner.js) { is.push_back(i); js.push_back(j); }

    size_type size1() const { return A.size1() - is.count(); }

    size_type size2() const { return A.size2() - js.count(); }
    const_reference operator () (size_type i_, size_type j_) const
    {
        // I think this is correct for nested matrix_minors
        for (size_type i : is)
        {
            i_ += i_ >= i;
        }
        for (size_type j : js)
        {
            j_ += j_ >= j;
        }
        return A(i_, j_);
    }

private:
    const Matrix& A;
    vector<unsigned int> is, js;
};
```

Comment: Thanks this is the better way of doing it - although I suspect I'll have to modify the logic a bit as when constructing a minor of a minor it needs to work out which i and j of the original matrix this corresponds to

Comment: Yes, I wasn't quite sure how the indexes should work

Answer (score 4):

`templates` are instantiated on compile-time. Your calculations are not in compile-time, so, compiler can't see, that there is the end of instantiations and instantiate max times.

For example in gcc this will be:

```
In instantiation of ‘B<T>::B(const T&) [with T = B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<B<A<int> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > >]’:
new.cpp:34:35:   recursively required from ‘typename T::type foo(const T&) [with T = B<A<int> >]’
new.cpp:34:35:   required from ‘typename T::type foo(const T&) [with T = A<int>]’
new.cpp:39:18:   required from here
new.cpp:22:27: fatal error: template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900 (use -ftemplate-depth= to increase the maximum)
     B(const T& t) : t(t) {}
```

template recursion can be done like this:

```
template<int N>
constexpr int factorial()
{
   return N * factorial<N - 1>();
}

template<>
constexpr int factorial<0>()
{
   return 1;
}
```

here compiler know, that there is specific action when `N` is zero, that stops recursion.

Your example can be something like that. Note: using C++17 `if constexpr`.

```
template <typename T, T N>
class A
{
public:
    typedef T type;
    static constexpr type value = N;

    static constexpr type get_value() { return value; }
};

template <typename T>
class B
{
public:
    typedef typename T::type type;

    static constexpr type get_value() { return T::get_value() - 1; }
};

template <typename T>
typename T::type foo()
{
    if constexpr(T::get_value() == 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return T::get_value() + foo<B<T>>();
}
```

[Live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/8PevpYx7Aj3iJQzS)

Comment: I'm not sure the if constexpr helps him with his actual problem involving expression templates.

Comment: @Caleth I'm almost sure that will not, however, cause I don't know actual code - I rewrote code, that OP have in question.

Comment: except that your class A requires a compile time value, whereas his accepts run time values

Comment: @Caleth ye. well, it's impossible to use template recursion with runtime values as I know.

Comment: Thanks for this, I understand the problem now but I can't use compile time values so I will have to think of another solution; possiblyto make two B classes, one which holds a reference to an A instance as a member and the second which holds a reference to a B instance. Then I can overload foo to accept any of A or the two B classes and thus just remove the templates altogether. A little more code than I was hoping to write but hopefully less headaches.